# Subfigure, submat and easy to-do packages - Command \c@lofdepth already defined. \newcounter{lofdepth}

Tags: subfloats, texstudio, easy-todo

UPDATE:

### Added the command \PassOptionsToPackage{subfigure}{tocloft} before the easy-todo package, according to the answers, and it solved the problem! :)

I have this error when i try to use subfigure, submat package and easy-todo:

Command \c@lofdepth already defined. \newcounter{lofdepth}

I tried some of the suggestions given in other questions, however they did not work. And i really need to maintain the notes.

Does anyone can help me fix it?

Thanks in advance!

```
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{subfigmat}
%Quick notes.
\PassOptionsToPackage{subfigure}{tocloft} %SOLUTION - added line
\usepackage{easy-todo}
%\usepackage[disable]{easy-todo} 

\begin{document}

Text with an important note \todo{Note}.
Figure bellow:

\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=12cm,height=9cm]{Figure.JPG}
    \caption{Figure to test.}
    \label{fig:test}
\end{figure}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you please add a minimal example so that we can reproduce your problem?

Comment: Just good guessing: When using the `tocloft` package you need to specifiy the option `subfigure`: `\usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft}`

Comment: @MarianaMoreira But easy-todo uses the `tocloft` package. So `\PassOptionsToPackage{subfigure}{tocloft}` before loading the `easy-todo` package should help.

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt I didn't knew! Thank you so much! It solved the problem!